# Force Thread to timeout with ThreadPoolExecutor

Tags: python, multithreading, timeout, threadpool

I'm upgrading my code to work with the ThreadPoolExecuter and want to be able to timeout any threads that take longer than a few seconds to process. Is it possible to force a timeout on a Thread that is part of a thread pool? The code I am working with is below.

```
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=16) as executor:
        future_tasks = {executor.submit(self.crawl_task, url): url for url in self.results.keys()}

        for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(future_tasks):
            url = future_tasks[future]
            try:
                result = future.result()
                self.results[result[0]] = result[1]
            except Exception as e:
                print('%r generated an exception: %s' % (url, e))
```

The only way I have been able to timeout a thread is by changing

```
for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(future_tasks):
```

to

```
for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(future_tasks, timeout=1):
```

This however, will break the entire loop and I won't be able to know which thread timed out and what data caused the timeout.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 75, in <module>
    request = Requests(data)
  File "test.py", line 22, in __init__
    for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(future_tasks, timeout=1):
  File "/source/homebrew/Cellar/python3/3.4.0_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/    lib/python3.4/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 213, in as_completed
    len(pending), len(fs)))
concurrent.futures._base.TimeoutError: 17 (of 17) futures unfinished
```

Answer (score 2):

Wrapping the entire for loop for futures in an exception still allows other threads results to process. Using two separate dictionaries, you can see which threads stopped due to a Timeout.

```
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=16) as executor:
    future_tasks = {executor.submit(self.crawl_task, url): url for url in self.requests.keys()}

    try:
        for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(future_tasks, timeout=10):
            result = future.result()
            self.responses[result[0]] = result[1]
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

timeout = [url for url in self.requests.keys() if url not in self.responses.keys()]

print('URL Threads timed out: ', timeout)
```

I have to point out that this goes against conventional wisdom. Typically if you wrap an entire for loop in an exception, anything after the exception in the loop should not process but the magic of futures seems to allow everything in the loop (except for the thread that timed out) to process.

Comment: thanks this answers solves my problem. however, I am still a bit confused about this magic and did not find anything about it in the docs.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is by logging the url in a file at the start of execution in self.crawl_task. Before the thread task completes, it can append a string "DONE" and perhaps with a timestamp.

Also, You need to handle that TimeoutError exception to not let the execution break. If there is a timeout, you can look into file logs that does not have "DONE" string in it.

Comment: This will cause the entire loop to break though and will loose data from several other threads that did not timeout. Analyzing log files is not an ideal method for managing thread states.

Comment: You can do something like embedding "for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(future_tasks): " in a try block and ignore the exception. You can ignore by simply flagging this condition for you to review the logs.

Comment: That will cause all threads to timeout. How do I timeout a single thread without timing out the entire thread pool?

Comment: There seem to be timeout support in result() .For e.g. result(timeout=None)

Comment: I saw the other stackoverflow post that posted that and tried it. It doesn't actually cause a timeout and couldn't find any documentation regarding it.

Comment: Alright. So, the timeout needs to be programmed inside crawl_task.

Comment: There is a timeout check in the crawl_task. However, when this is added to production code the complexity will be much higher. Also, the timeout on requests is not 100% reliable and there needs to be a way to timeout threads.

Comment: In your answer, I see that you have embedded the for loop in the try block and the execution continued. This is how Python exception works mostly. Unfortunately, there was no way for me to confirm the Future behavior as I did not have access to a terminal with python 3.